# How can successful small caps outperform large caps, when they become large caps?

Tags: asset-pricing

For example, pretend that some [S&P 600](https://old.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/98aoa0/sp_600_consistently_outperforming_sp_500/e4g5sc3/) corporation succeeds and profits, like [some biotech](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/portfolio/VIOO/portfolio-holdings) discovers [multiple cures to disease](https://www.pharmatutor.org/pharmapedia/top-incurable-diseases-in-medical-science-cancer-asthma-hiv-aids-common-cold-polio-ebola-influenza?page=1) like cancer. Assume that its market capitalization then skyrockets enough that it becomes a large cap and joins the S&P 400 or S&P 500.

1. Wouldn't it join either of the larger S&P indices? Are there reasons that it'd choose to remain S&P 600?
2. If so, then this former small cap has become a large cap. So how can [small caps historically outperform large caps after recessions](https://www.blog.invesco.us.com/small-cap-stocks-have-historically-outperformed-after-recessions/)?

Comment: There is no choice here.  The indices are decided by FTSE Russell based on market capitalization

Comment: @Henry Thanks. I've changed Russell to S&P now.

Comment: What is the logic behind (2)? Empirical effects in equities - to the extent they exist - are presumably related to how a group of companies acts, and not the fate of one firm. Most large caps were previously smaller companies, and membership changes are an ongoing process.